# Issue regarding store file data into an array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, file, parsing

I have a text file (.txt) which contains an array and the elements of these array is in string format but these are also arrays. Just like the following:

For example, lets consider my file as:

```
["[1, 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000, \"ho\"]","[1, 2016-11-18 07:38:29 +0000, \"hose cla\"]", "[1, 2016-11-18 08:24:54 +0000, \"mo\"]"]
```

I need to put this file data into an array.The array will look like as follows:

```
array = ["[1, 2016-11-18 07:38:26 +0000, \"ho\"]","[1, 2016-11-18 07:38:29 +0000, \"hose cla\"]", "[1, 2016-11-18 08:24:54 +0000, \"mo\"]"]
```

Right now I am unable to put the data of the file into the array using the following code statements. I am not getting the required format.

My code is:

```
arr=[]
arr=File.open('input.txt').map { |line| line.split(',"') }
puts arr
```

Help me how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: In what way are you "not getting the required format"? What are you getting? Furthermore, what is generating this file? Are you using a standard data serialization format like JSON or YAML?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to parse it as JSON. That should give you the output you're looking for.

```
require 'json'
raw = File.open('input.txt').read
array = JSON.parse(raw)
```